# Multiple GeoTIFFs in a single layer from S3

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I am wondering does GeoServer have a way that I can render multiple .tiff files as one layer, with those being in an S3 bucket/folder. My current solution is using the COG plugin for GeoTIFF store (which allows only pointing to a single file) which results in one layer per TIFF and then I make a layer group out of a few GeoTIFF layers. Is there a better way to do this and have multiple GeoTIFFs as one layer? I tried tampering with ImageMosaic but it seems the files need to be local and even using ImageMosaic with local files my GeoTIFFs that are usually diagonal are being made vertical and widened when rendered and not sure if it supports overlapping images as well.